# Group by with applying a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to get a list of points after performing an aggregation.
Suppose that I have the following dataset:

```
AC_ID,AC_PERIOD,ROU_ROUTE_ID,SEQUENCE_NR,SEG_POINT_FROM_ID,SEG_POINT_TO_ID
502,S,A1,1,BRY,LUREN
502,S,A1,2,LUREN,DJL
502,S,A1,3,DJL,LISMO
502,S,A1,4,LISMO,SIROD
502,S,A100,1,KL,*ROS1
502,S,A100,2,*ROS1,AMEPU
502,S,A100,3,AMEPU,SARZI
```

In the end, I wish to have:

```
A1,[BRY, LUREN, DJL, LISMO]
A100,[KL, *ROS1, AMEPU, SARZI]
```

As you can see, I would group by the ROU_ROUTE_IDand get all the elements from SEG_POINT_FROM_ID + the last element of SEG_POINT_TO_ID.

In order to do this I started using a group by and i want to apply a function that I will create before in order to do the logic with the points.

something like this:

```
data.groupby('ROU_ROUTE_ID')[['SEG_POINT_FROM_ID','SEG_POINT_TO_ID']].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

My problem is that I can't access the two columns in the f(x).

I think there is a faster way of doing this calculation but I am stuck for hours on this.

I was also considering about doing an iterative algorithm without using pandas, but i don't know if it will be more optimized than using pandas out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


def testfun(x):
    print(x["b"])
    print(x["c"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = pd.DataFrame({
        "a": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "b": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "c": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    })
    test.groupby("a")[["b", "c"]].apply(testfun)
```

I'm not sure what the problem you're having is. You can access the columns inside the applied function just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can access two columns in your lambda function by using the `apply()` and passing `x` as a DataFrame with the two columns you want to use:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'AC_ID': [502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502],
    'AC_PERIOD': ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'],
    'ROU_ROUTE_ID': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A100', 'A100', 'A100'],
    'SEQUENCE_NR': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3],
    'SEG_POINT_FROM_ID': ['BRY', 'LUREN', 'DJL', 'LISMO', 'KL', '*ROS1', 'AMEPU'],
    'SEG_POINT_TO_ID': ['LUREN', 'DJL', 'LISMO', 'SIROD', '*ROS1', 'AMEPU', 'SARZI']
})


def f(x):
    return x['SEG_POINT_FROM_ID'].tolist() + [x['SEG_POINT_TO_ID'].iloc[-1]]


result = data.groupby('ROU_ROUTE_ID').apply(f)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
ROU_ROUTE_ID
A1      [BRY, LUREN, DJL, LISMO, SIROD]
A100          [KL, *ROS1, AMEPU, SARZI]
```

Answer (score 0):

A sample for your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'val1':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
                   'val2':['b','c','a','w','f','g','h','y']})

df
```

Function to get unique value from two columns:

```
def func_unique(g):
    tem = g['val1'].tolist() + g['val2'].tolist()
    tem = list(set(tem))
    return tem
```

Using `groupby` and `apply` to get the desired result:

```
df.groupby('name').apply(func_unique).reset_index(name='anything')
```